# How can multiple threads corrupt internal structure of Hashmap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-8

In `Java 8 for the Really Impatient` Horstmann writes:

> If multiple threads modify a plain HashMap, they can destroy the
>   internal structure. Some of the links may go missing, or even go in
>   circles, rendering the data structure unusable. (**Section 6.2.1**)

I can understand that unsynchronized concurrent access can corrupt my data. If both two threads update same value one can overwrite the other.

But why and how would it corrupt the internal memory structure?

Comment: Internal memory means the `thing` - some `Colleciton of Entry` internal structure of `HashMap` implementation that keeps data for `HashMap`.

Comment: If you understand that unsynchronized concurrent access can corrupt “your data” it should be a small step realizing that it can corrupt the structure of a `HashMap` as well as “your data” and “the internal memory structure” of a `HashMap` is the same thing: a bunch of objects on the Java heap.

Comment: @Holger And the computer and my lunch box are the same thing because they're plastic. Data is user provided values, internal structure is pointers in the underlying data structure. How does corrupting salary amount from 5000 to -3838 mess up the pointers isn't overtly obvious. Hence the question.

Comment: @Kshitiz Sharma: Why do you think the computer makes a distinction between “user provided values” and “pointers in the underlying data structure”? The CPU doesn’t know what a “user” is nor does it know who has provided the bytes it processes. I recommend reading “Java Concurrency in Practice” by Brian Goetz et al if you really want to go into multithreaded programming.

Comment: @Holger `The computer` doesn't. The `JVM` does and should. It's not possible to access memory references from Java. When it's not possible to even access these how could one corrupt these? Shouldn't `Java` manage them well? Not overtly obvious. Hence the question.

Comment: @Kshitiz Sharma: the JVM still doesn’t make a difference between “user provided values” and other values. Sure, it does not allow you to to manipulate memory the way `C` does but `HashMap`, being a pure Java class, does not use such a facility either. What you think to be “internal memory structure” is still plain data inside an ordinary Java class just like your classes. The guarantees the JVM makes for an `int` or an object reference are the same: they will never contain random data without a source. But without synchronization they may be outdated or inconsistent.

Comment: If you can share the link for Section 6.2.1.

Comment: @quintin The quote is from a book which is not free. You'll have to buy it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer you are seeking is perfectly explained in [this](http://mailinator.blogspot.gr/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html) blog post.

If you read through it you will see that a race condition can among other things corrupt the pointers between items in a bucket, thus causing a lookup to turn into an infinite traversal between two items.

I am not exactly sure how much the implementation of `HashMap` has changed for Java 8, but I suspect that the basics still apply.

I should also add that this problem is not too difficult to encounter, I have actually seen it happen in a real life production system!